# How to draw 3D vectors and coordinates of points

Tags: graphics3d

Draw 2D vectors and coordinates of points:

```
Graphics[{Red, Arrow[{{1, 0}, {2, 1}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}, Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {{Text["(1,0)", {1, 0.1}], Text["(2,1)", {2, 1.1}], Blue, 
    PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0}], Point[{2, 1}]}}]
```

However, the code cannot draw vectors and coordinates of points in 3D:

```
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{{1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 Epilog -> {{Text["(1,0,0)", {1, .1, 0}], 
    Text["(2,1,0)", {2, 1.1, 0}], Blue, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point[{1, 0, 0}], Point[{2, 1, 0}]}}]
```

How to draw 3D vectors and coordinates of points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrow[{{1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}]}, {Blue, 
   PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0, 0}], 
   Point[{2, 1, 0}]}, {Text["(1,0,0)", {1, .1, 0}], 
   Text["(2,1,0)", {2, 1.1, 0}]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! @cvgmt

Comment: `Graphics3D[{{Red, Arrow[{{1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}}]}, {Blue, 
   PointSize[Medium], Point[{1, 0, 0}], 
   Point[{2, 1, 0}]}, {Text[
    Style["(1,0,0)", Cyan], {1, .1, 0}, {1.5, 1}], 
   Text[Style["(2,1,0)", Green], {2, 1.1, 0}, {-1, -1}]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 3}, {-2, 3}, {-2, 3}}, Axes -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]`

Comment: Thank you! This graph is better than the previous one. @cvgmt